# Does .remove() gets skipped if .trigger() is present

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not certain about the complexity of the code that I have right now which is:

```
$(document).on('click', '#filter-items span i', function(e) {
    var filter_value    = $(this).parent().attr('data-value');
    var filter_field    = $(this).parent().attr('data-field');

    $( this ).parent().remove();

    $('#the-filters input[name="' + filter_field +'"][value="' +filter_value +'"]').trigger('click');

});
```

And the selected filter item structure is:

```
<div id="filter-items">
    <span data-value="14" class="filter-item" data-field="category">Filter 1<i class="fas fa-times"></i></span>
</div>
```

The issue that I cannot seem to figure out is that if:

```
$('#the-filters input[name="' + filter_field +'"][value="' +filter_value +'"]').trigger('click');
```

Is present on the code, it stops

```
$( this ).parent().remove();
```

from being executed. Is there any reason why this is happening? I tried to put the remove line in an if statement and place the trigger code inside it but the same thing happens.

Comment: Maybe triggering click causes the span to be recreated?

Comment: Yeah okay, I'm being dumb! That was it. OMG. <3 @Bemmu

Comment: Alright, I added an answer too, because I'm karma-greedy.

Comment: You deserve it! Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Triggering .click causes the span to be recreated, so that's why the removal appears to not be working.